# reversing the string without any predefined function in c

Tags: c

i am using below code, i don't knw what i doing wrong.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{

    char a[5];
    char ptr[5] = "hello";
    int i,j,k=0;

    for(i=0;ptr[i] !='\0'&&ptr[i]!=' ';i++){}
    k=i;
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        a[j] = ptr[k];
        printf("%c %c %d %d %d\n",a[j],ptr[k],i,j,k);
        k--;
    }
    printf("%s %s",a,ptr);
}
```

Output:

```
  5 0 5
o o 5 1 4
l l 5 2 3
l l 5 3 2
e e 5 4 1
h h 5 5 0
 hello
```

Comment: `char ptr[5] = "hello";` not enough space in `ptr` will cause buffer-overflow. C strings need  an additional space for string delimiter `\0`

Comment: `[5]` -> `[6]`.

Comment: Or `[5]`->`[]` and let the compiler count

Comment: `    k = i -1;
    for(j=0; j<i; j++)`

Comment: @SparKot Should be clarified: the initialization itself will not cause buffer overflow on its own. It is valid to initialize a buffer whose size is one less than the size of the string literal, in which case the null byte is simply ignored. The result is no longer a *string*, of course, and using it as one will surely lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you're looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    char a[6];
    char ptr[6] = "hello";
    int i,j,k=0;

    for(i=0;ptr[i] !='\0'&&ptr[i]!=' ';i++){}
    k= i - 1;
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        a[j] = ptr[k];
        printf("%c %c %d %d %d\n",a[j],ptr[k],i,j,k);
        k--;
    }
    printf("%s %s",a,ptr);
}
```

Comment: It's almost right but printed some garbage in beginning like "�olleh"

Comment: Did you copy/paste the code or manually modified yours?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer for undefined length of input string. Have a look :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main(){
    char a[10];
    char ptr[10];

    scanf("%s", ptr);

    for(int i = 0, j = strlen(ptr)-1; j != -1; i++, j--){
        a[i] = ptr[j];
    }
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

Comment: it is not to complicate, i done this way coz when the length of the string undetermined

Comment: @MohamedAareesh I have edited my post for unlengthed strings